# SQLAlchemy not committing update

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am get some unexpected behavior when trying to commit an update with SQLalchemy..

I have an object like so..

```
updatedINfo = {'id': 1, 'type': 'NewData'}
# The ID is an id from the table, the 'type' is a column from that table
# The 'NewData' is what needs to replace whatever is currently stored in
# 'type' column.
```

Because I want this function to be reusble and not have to hardcode the column names, I figured I could do something like this;

```
# Find the event first
the_event = db.query(EventsPending).filter(EventsPending.id == updatedInfo.get('id')).one_or_none()

# If it returns None, something went wrong
if not the_event:
    return {'Error': 'Something went wrong..'}

# Take the id out of the JSON post
del updatedInfo['id']

# Turn our db query into a dict
event_dict = the_event.as_dict()

# Set the keys for cross checking
for key in event_dict.keys():
    if key in updatedInfo.keys():
        the_event.__dict__[key] = updatedInfo.get(key)
        print(the_event.type)
        # THIS PRINTS THE UPDATED TYPE
        print(the_event.as_dict())
        # THIS ALSO PRINTS THE UPDATED TYPE

       db.commit()
       print(the_event.type)
       # HOWEVER THIS PRINTS THE OLD TYPE AFTER THE COMMIT
       # The commit does not make it to the database
       # I see no errors, and logging shows no useful info
```

Obviously I can work around this by coding in the different types but really seems ugly and inefficient. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this.. You need

```
setattr(the_event, key, data)
# the_event being the sqlalchemy object
# key being the column name
# data being the new value
```

Hope this helps someone.